# Unable to tap on Choose or Cancel Image selection in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I can't choose an image in UIImagePickerController. When I press on choose button my picker is not interactive anymore. I can only dismiss it. Here is what im getting in error log

UpdatedWebantGallery[75511:6760388] [xpc.exceptions] <NSXPCConnection: 0x6000025c2d00> connection on anonymousListener or serviceListener from pid 75514: Warning: Exception caught during invocation of selector didSelectMediaWithInfoDictionary:, dropping incoming message and invalidating the connection.
Exception: *** -[NSURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:]: component, components, or pathExtension cannot be nil.
*** -[NSURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:]: component, components, or pathExtension cannot be nil.

And Here is my code of ViewController

```
class AddPhotoSceneViewController: UIViewController {
internal var presenter: AddPhotoScenePresenter!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
let tapGestureRecgonizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tapGestureRecgonizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showAlertSheet))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecgonizer)
    
    setupAlert()
    
    self.setLeftNavBarCancelButtonView(target: self, selector: #selector(self.returnToGalleryScreenTab))
}

func setupAlert() {
    let uploadFromCameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Upload photo from camera", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.picker.sourceType = .camera
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { response in
            if response {
                //access granted
            } else {
                
            }
        }
        self.invokePicker()
    }
    let uploadFromGalleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Upload photo from gallery", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        switch PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(){
        case .authorized:
            self.invokePicker()
        case .denied:
            let modalView = ModalPopUpViewController(title: "Access Denied",
                                                     text: "If you want to upload your own photo we need your access to open gallery",
                                                     buttontext: "Open Settings",
                                                     action: #selector(self.openSettings),
                                                     target: self)
            self.present(modalView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        default:
            return
        }
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        return
    }
    
    self.actionSheet.addAction(uploadFromCameraAction)
    self.actionSheet.addAction(uploadFromGalleryAction)
    self.actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)
}

@objc func dismissModalView() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func openSettings() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if let url = URL.init(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}

@objc func showAlertSheet() {
    self.present(self.actionSheet, animated: true) {
        return
    }
}

@objc func routeToAddPhotoForm() {
    self.presenter?.routeToAddPhotoForm(image: self.imageView.image!)
}

@objc func returnToGalleryScreenTab() {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}

func invokePicker() {
    self.picker.allowsEditing = true
    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.present(self.picker, animated: true)
}
}

extension AddPhotoSceneViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }

    let imageName = UUID().uuidString
    let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName)

    if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
        try? jpegData.write(to: imagePath)
    }
    
    self.imageView.image = image
    self.setRightNavBarButtonView(title: "Next",target: self, selector: #selector(self.routeToAddPhotoForm))

    dismiss(animated: true)
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}
}
```

I Have no idea why it can be happening.

Here is a screen where I'm getting stopped

[image]

Comment: you should dismiss the `picker`

Answer (score 0):

Copy/pasting your implementation here -

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
        // Add a print statement here to check whether we are returning from here
        print("Could not find editedImage")
        
        // if you are returning from here, then `dismiss` call at the end is not being executed
        // hence your picker never gets dismissed

        // try using info[.originalImage] in case you end up here
        return 
    }

    let imageName = UUID().uuidString
    let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName)

    if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
        try? jpegData.write(to: imagePath)
    }
    
    self.imageView.image = image
    self.setRightNavBarButtonView(title: "Next",target: self, selector: #selector(self.routeToAddPhotoForm))

    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

When `Cancel` is pressed, [`UIImagePickerController.imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619133-imagepickercontrollerdidcancel) is called.

> Your delegate’s implementation of this method should dismiss the picker view by calling the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` method of the parent view controller.
>
> **Implementation of this method is optional, but expected.**

You should copy/paste following method to your code.

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```